# $\int f(x) x^n dx=0$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Tags: integration, uniform-convergence

This problem is similar to Baby Rudin Excercise 20 in chapter 7. The problem states that $g:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and that for all natural $n\geq 1$, $\int_0^1 g(x) x^n dx=0$. Prove that $g\equiv 0$. We do NOT know that $\int_0^1 g(x)dx=0$. (The Rudin exercise has the additional assumption that this holds for $n=0$ as well) I know that this implies that $\int_0^1 g(x)dx=\int_0^1 g(x)^2dx$ but am unable to conclude from here.

Comment: Note: $g(x)^2$ is always non-negative. If $g(x) \neq 0$, then $g(x)^2 > 0$! Use this plus continuity to prove that the integral of $g^2$ would then be positive.

Comment: It would be nice when referring to an exercise in a book to state what that exercise says, especially for those who don't have the book.

Comment: I edited that thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hint. We know that $\int_0^1 (xg(x)) x^n dx=0$ for all $n\geq 0$. Now apply Baby Rudin Exercise to the continuous function $xg(x)$.

Comment: Thank you very much...that makes it much easier. So then you could theoretically replace $n\geq 1$ by $n\geq 42$ (or any other integer?) and make the same conclusion?

Comment: @AdamMartens Yes, you are correct.